# sql store date when just the decade / century is known

Tags: sql, date

i have a list of books i want to store in a database. one of the attributes is the date when the book was first published. of the older books (older than 100 years) i often just know the decade (like 185X) or in case of the *very old* books just the century (like 15XX).

how would you save those dates in a datetime2 field? 15XX as 1500? i want to be able to query for books which are older than a hundred years, for example. so i somehow want to store those values as a valid datetime2 value. any recommendations? 15XX as '1500-01-01 00:00' seems reasonable to me. any drawbacks of that approach?

Comment: You might want to consider a flag column indicating the level of precision, or at a minimum setting the time-part of the datetime to a magic value that your application will interpret as "date not exact." There ought to be some way to tell, later, which dates are exact and which are approximate (and hopefully how approximate!)

Comment: personally i've used a similar approach where by my unknowns were all 0's. Otherwise you could build a simple class that holds a date and a value that indicates how much of the date is known, by precession (i.e. 10, 100 meaning closest decade, century).

Comment: Another alternative is to store 2 dates representing the publication date range, the values are the same when the date is exact else they span the entire candidate range

Comment: As ever ***it depends***.  The more flexibility, the more overheads; code/maintenance/performance.  So, define how you need to use your data, *then* determine the best fit data representation.  *[There is no universal magic bullet that is best fit to all use-cases, sorry.]*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only drawback is when someone asks for all books published from 1550 to 1650. Your 15XX became 1500, so it won't be included in his results.

What you really have is a period of uncertainty when given book was published. I'd store 2 dates: one when the period started, and the other when ended. Modern books will have it set to same dates, but the oldest ones can be stored as 1500-01-01 00:00 - 1599-12-31 23:59

Of course it will complicate selects. You have to decide if it's worth it. You may declare that asking for "1550 to 1650" is plain stupid.

Answer (score 3):

In extension to @dragon112's answer, is there the possibility that you would need `15XX` as BOTH of the first two options?  *(In the same way as NULL is and isn't any value, at the same time.)*

- the oldest possible date for that book (for 15xx it would be 1500)
- the youngest possible date for that book (for 15xx it would be 1599)

If so, you could store two dates and make a date range within which the book was published.

This does make your queries/system more complex.  When writing the SQL bot of these are syntactically correct, but you'd need to pick which is appropriate in any given situation, as they *could* give different results...

```
WHERE
  earliestPublishDate > '1550-01-01'

WHERE
  latestPublishDate > '1550-01-01'
```

So, the most important question when determining how to store your data:
- How are you going to interrogate it?

You need to know your use-cases (or *likely* use cases) in order to determine your correct data representation.

Comment: Actually, with two columns, queries would simply need to include both dates: `'1550-01-01' BETWEEN earliestPublishDate AND latestPublishDate` (testing against a single date), `'1559-12-31' >= earliestPublishDate AND '1550-01-01' <= latestPublishDate` (testing against a period). More complex than with a single column, yes, but if you *do* need to store imprecise dates, this seems an optimal solution.

Comment: @AndriyM - My example was meant to highlight the different interpretations of "Published in or after 1550".  The first WHERE clause would give "*categorically* published after 1550" where as the second would give "anything that *could* have been published after 1550".

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that by "more complex" you meant to point out a possibly reduced efficiency of the system, while in actual fact, I guess, your example kind of explored the *positive* side of the increased complexity, in the sense that the system would allow one to build queries with this additional bit of "precisiveness" to them (as well as it would be capable of including that bit into the output).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there are 3 ways of saving the date of such books:

- the oldest possible date for that book (for 15xx it would be 1500)
- the youngest possible date for that book (for 15xx it would be 1599)
- halfway the above (for 15xx it would be 1550)

These approaches are irrelevant for the code itself, but they will influence your results when you query for a certain age. So whatever feels best for you should be fine in my opinion.

In other words when you query for a book of 500 years old would you want to get a book that is from 15xx or not? As it is the year 2012 right now the book will not be returned by the database (2012 - 500 = 1512).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, I would consider the following solution:

Save the values as two fields on the database.
The first are stored in the format as you mentioned '1500-01-01 00:00' for sorting purposes.  The second field are used to record the original value 15XX, its data type is of an alphanumeric type.

With this approach you are not losing the fact that the data is unknown.  But you still you meet your requirement of searching for books older than a certain date.

The date time field is then strictly a calculated from the alphanumeric field.

Comment: i very much like that suggestion. in case i come up with a better solution later i still have access to the original verbatim value of the date field.

Comment: @lightxx It's not "verbatim" at all. You have already forced someone to discard some data by entering "15XX". He could had known more specific period, like 1510-1560. Or how to enter a book first published 1899-1901? There are 3 possibilities: 190X, 19XX, or 1XXX and you'll never know what the guy meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no need to store time with date then use datatype "Date", no need to go for datetime2 to just allowing date from 01-01-0001.

Date also support dates from 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31. Datetime2 has more time accuracy than datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100)
SET @var = ''
SET @var =  CASE LEN(@var) 
                WHEN 1 THEN @var + '000' 
                WHEN 2 THEN @var + '00' 
                WHEN 3 THEN @var + '0' 
                ELSE @var 
            END
SELECT CAST(@var AS DATE)
```